# Would a pre-calculated variable faster than calculating it every time in a loop?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

In a function that updates all particles I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _maxParticles; i++)
{
    // check if active
    if (_particles[i].lifeTime > 0.0f)
    {
        _particles[i].lifeTime -= _decayRate * deltaTime;
    }
}
```

This decreases the lifetime of the particle based on the time that passed.
It gets calculated every loop, so if I've 10000 particles, that wouldn't be very efficient because it doesn't need to(it doesn't get changed anyways).

So I came up with this:

```
float lifeMin = _decayRate * deltaTime;

for (int i = 0; i < _maxParticles; i++)
{
    // check if active
    if (_particles[i].lifeTime > 0.0f)
    {
        _particles[i].lifeTime -= lifeMin;
    }
}
```

This calculates it once and sets it to a variable that gets called every loop, so the CPU doesn't have to calculate it every loop, which would theoretically increase performance.

Would it run faster than the old code? Or does the release compiler do optimizations like this?

I wrote a program that compares both methods:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

const unsigned int MAX = 1000000000;

int main()
{
    float deltaTime = 20;
    float decayRate = 200;

    float foo = 2041.234f;

    unsigned int start = clock();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        foo -= decayRate * deltaTime;
    }

    std::cout << "Method 1 took " << clock() - start << "ms\n";

    start = clock();

    float calced = decayRate * deltaTime;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        foo -= calced;
    }

    std::cout << "Method 2 took " << clock() - start << "ms\n";

    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    return 0;
}
```

Result in debug mode:

```
Method 1 took 2470ms
Method 2 took 2410ms
```

Result in release mode:

```
Method 1 took 0ms
Method 2 took 0ms
```

But that doesn't work. I know it doesn't do exactly the same, but it gives an idea.
In debug mode, they take roughly the same time. Sometimes Method 1 is faster than Method 2(especially at fewer numbers), sometimes Method 2 is faster.
In release mode, it takes 0 ms. A little weird.

I tried measuring it in the game itself, but there aren't enough particles to get a clear result.

**EDIT**
I tried to disable optimizations, and let the variables be user inputs using `std::cin`.
Here are the results:

```
Method 1 took 2430ms
Method 2 took 2410ms
```

Comment: Most probably both versions end up in the same code. Look at the generated assembler code to confirm.

Comment: unused expressions are discarded.  Provably unchanging data is precalculated.  In some compilers (more rare) loops can be turned inside out if that can be shown by the compiler to be equivalent.  All such optimizations are fragile.  Profiling with optimizations off is pointless: with it on requires care.

Comment: Re the edit: in other words, the difference isn't significant (and is well within the variance you'd expect even if the two generated exactly the same code).  So write what is clearest, and forget about such micro-optimizations.

Comment: Re the timings with optimization: if you don't use the results (`foo`), the compiler will probably remove the loops entirely.  Even if you use them, the compiler might replace the loops with something like `foo -= MAX * decayRate * deltaTime;`.  Benchmarking such things is remarkable tricky, and usually counter productive, since what counts is what happens in your actual code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will almost certainly make no difference what so ever, at least if
you compile with optimization (and of course, if you're concerned with
performance, you are compiling with optimization).  The opimization in
question is called loop invariant code motion, and is universally
implemented (and has been for about 40 years).

On the other hand, it *may* make sense to use the separate variable
anyway, to make the code clearer.  This depends on the application, but
in many cases, giving a name to the results of an expression can make
code clearer.  (In other cases, of course, throwing in a lot of extra
variables can make it less clear.  It's all depends on the application.)
In any case, for such things, write the code as clearly as possible
first, and then, if (and only if) there is a performance problem,
profile to see where it is, and fix that.

EDIT:

Just to be perfectly clear: I'm talking about this sort of code optimization in general.  In the exact case you show, since you don't use `foo`, the compiler will probably remove it (and the loops) completely.

Comment: [Loop invariant *code* motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion).

Comment: Although the OP didn't show the actual code (not in the benchmark), if either `_decayRate` or `deltaTime` are not local variables (such as member variables), the compiler may need to assume that they could alias with `_particles[i].lifeTime`. In which case, the compiler cannot do the optimization.

Comment: @Mysticial They can only alias if there are references involved somewhere.  Which is (or should be) highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes. But your loop is extremely simple and thus likeley to be heavily optimized.

Try the `-O0` option to disable all compiler optimizations.

The release runtime might be caused by the compiler statically computing the result.

I am pretty confident that any decent compiler will replace your loops with the following code:

```
foo -= MAX * decayRate * deltaTime;
```

and

```
foo -= MAX * calced ;
```

You can make the MAX size depending on some kind of input (e.g. command line parameter) to avoid that.

Comment: --1 - profiling with disabled optimizations is nearly always pointless.  Suggesting it like that makes this answer to be likely less than useful.

Comment: He doesn't use `foo`, ever.  So any decent compiler will eliminate it completely (and also suppress the loops).